# Why Can't I Use Unity 3D on an HP Pavilion g4?

Tags: unity, ati, hybrid-graphics

I have recently bought a new computer and loaded Ubuntu 12.04 along side Windows 7. I have run `/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p` and receive a no on Not Software Rendered, yes on everything else. I don't know what this means or how to change it. I also can't figure out what command to use to provide the short list of my system hardware so that I can present it here. Please help!

I am using a HP Pavilion g4, purchased a week ago from best buy. It has a AMD Radeon HD 6480G graphics card with the VESA: Intel®Sandybridge Mobile Graphics driver. This is a brand new computer so I can't imagine it would not be able to run Unity. One thing of note would be that I had to install Ubuntu with nomodeset selected. I don't know if that is an issue here.

What can I do to get my system to run Unity 3D?

---

I followed the link you gave but didn't find that the video card I think I have is mentioned there. I checked my video card in the terminal and it says I have Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09). I don't think this is the same card Best Buy advertised the computer with but I don't know. Anyway, I'm not sure if this is an ATI driver so I didn't follow through with installing the drivers mentioned in the link you provided. What should I do?

---

Jorge, Thanks for the advice. Since I started this without signing up I cannot edit my previous posts and must keep adding new ones.

I'm not sure what info to include for you so I've attached some results here:

```
jeff@localhost:~$ sudo lspci -nn
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller [8086:0104] (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0106] (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 [8086:1c3a] (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 [8086:1c2d] (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller [8086:1c20] (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 [8086:1c10] (rev b5)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 [8086:1c12] (rev b5)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 [8086:1c14] (rev b5)
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 [8086:1c26] (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation HM65 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller [8086:1c49] (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port SATA AHCI Controller [8086:1c03] (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller [8086:1c22] (rev 05)
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT5390 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [1814:5390]
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 05)
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5116 PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:5209] (rev 01)

jeff@localhost:~$ /usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p
OpenGL vendor string:   VMware, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 0x300)
OpenGL version string:  2.1 Mesa 8.0.2

Not software rendered:    no
Not blacklisted:          yes
GLX fbconfig:             yes
GLX texture from pixmap:  yes
GL npot or rect textures: yes
GL vertex program:        yes
GL fragment program:      yes
GL vertex buffer object:  yes
GL framebuffer object:    yes
GL version is 1.4+:       yes

Unity 3D supported:       no
```

To reiterate, I'm using a new HP Pavilion g4 purchased from Best Buy. I could not install Ubuntu 12.04 with the regular install disc so I used the alternate disc with nomodeset selected. If I needed to change something within the system after doing this, I don't know what that is. Upon realizing that I was not running Unity but had Unity 2d, I started trying to figure out why but I could not find an explanation for this result online. Ubuntu currently has the VESA: Intel®Sandybridge Mobile Graphics driver running.

Update:

I installed the ATI binary X.Org driver. I then looked at additional drivers and nothing appears there! I restarted the system and still found no drivers there to enable. What else can I do?

Update2:

I am not running in a virtual machine. Ubuntu 12.04 is installed on its own partition on my hard drive. Can anybody tell me if there is something about my video card that is incompatible with Unity? I would imagine if it can run Windows 7 it can run Unity. I've tried everything here and have not been able to get anything to work.

Comment: [This](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI ) should help you install ATI drivers.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information?

Comment: Hi Jeff, the way this site works is you continuously edit this post with all the information you keep finding out, that will bump the question for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this out:
Click on the button below to take you to the Software Center. Install it, and then go back to `additional drivers` application and activate it. After that, restart your computer and hope for the best.

Hope this helps! Tell me if it works.

[image: Install via the software center]

Answer (score 0):

You apparently are running in a virtual machine, so Unity 3D probably would not run acceptably anyway.